# Open jQuery accordion panel with link (outside of acccordion)

Tags: jquery, accordion

Still new to jQuery!

I have an accordion that was built with the jQuery UI 1.10.1. It's pretty basic; the first item is showing by default, and the others are hidden until clicked on. I'd like to use links that exist above a jQuery accordion to open a certain accordion panel when clicked. It looks something like this:

Link1  Link2  Link3

| Accordion Header 1  |

| Accordion content 1 showing|

| Accordion Header 2  |

| Accordion content 2 hidden |

| Accordion Header 3  |

| Accordion content 3 hidden |

..so that when you click on "Link2", it hides Accordion content 1 and shows Accordion content 2.

I've searched the site and none of the answers seemed fitting.

Thanks

Comment: Please make a demo of your HTML at jsFiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably use a different method for linking the button to the header sections, I just used the id from the button.

But essentially:

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion();

$('.section-button').on('click', function(){
  var header = $('#accordion').find('.' + this.id);
  header.click();
});
```

[Demo here](http://jsbin.com/oyuwos/1/edit)

Answer (score 1):

As of Jul 1st 2018, if you run into this you can do:

```
$('#accordion').accordion({active:0})
```

Replace the 0 with the index of the tab. 0 will open the first, 1 the next etc..