# jQuery Accordion display specific tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, tabs

I'm rusty at javascript and HTML, and trying to get back into it.

Here's the sample code of the element I'd like to modify:

```
      <div id="tabContainer" class="table">
         <h1>Container</h1>
         <ul class="tabs">
            <li><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab3">Tab 3</a></li>                 
         </ul>
         <div id="tab_display">
            <div id="tab1" class="tab_content"></div>
            <div id="tab2" class="tab_content"></div>
            <div id="tab3" class="tab_content"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
```

I'm using a version of jQuery Accordion to switch between tabs,and it works without any trouble. Clicking on tab 2, while tab 1 is selected, will clear 'tab_display' and display the contents of tab 2.

I would like to control what tab is displayed, by clicking for a button for example.

If tab 1 is being displayed and I click another button on the page, I'd like for a specific tab to be displayed (show the selection on the 'tabs' list, and also show the contents in the 'tab_dsiplay').

How can I do this?
Thanks!

Comment: And what jQuery have you come up with to accomplish that? What does your intent look like? :)

Comment: An accordion is very different from a tab structure. Why are you confusing the two here?

Comment: Not confusing the two structures, I call them tabs but it's just how they look like. I'm using a website layout, and there's a file called tab-accordion >.>
The content selection uses accordion

Comment: Hmmm I've been using firebug and I think I see a solution to my problem... looks like simply settig the current <li> as active might do the trick

Comment: remove .active from the other class that has it aswell

Comment: Well I manage to set the correct "TAB" but not display its contents :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the solution here [open-jquery-accordion-panel-with-link-outside-of-acccordion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14991602/open-jquery-accordion-panel-with-link-outside-of-acccordion)

Demo [here](http://jsbin.com/oyuwos/1/edit?html,js,output).

Comment: Awesome! Can't believe I missed that question :D
Thank you my friend!